# Relevancy of standard deviation

Tags: probability, definition, standard-deviation, variance

I'm a maths student, and I have this very basic question in mind:

Why is standard deviation defined as the square root of the variance, when surely the expected value of the absolute value of the random variable itself minus its expected value, that is,

E |X-EX|

is closer to what "standard deviation" sounds like, isn't it ?
I'm sure there's a very good reason, don't get me wrong.

If you have any answers or comments, thanks in advance.

Dan

Comment: See: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that one :-)

Comment: You've reinvented _absolute deviation_. There are any number of technical reasons standard deviation is more helpful, but intuitively [it's related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3071375) to taxicab vs Euclidean length.