# Notation for "function from a subset of $X$ into $Y$"?

Tags: notation

The notation $f: X \to Y$ implies that $X$ is the domain of $f$. It is very regularly convenient to say something like:

> Let $U \subset X$ and $f: U \to Y$.

but in situations where the actual set $U$ isn't that important, just that it's a subset of $X$. Usually the subset will not be arbitrary, but will be implied by the context. The kind of thing I'm thinking of is:

> Let $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a plane curve.

Is there a common choice for notation in this case? I imagine there must be (it might even be $\hookrightarrow$ but I'm not certain, I think that might mean injective).

The notation does **not** have to encode that the required subset is connected or open or whatever the situtation might require. That should be implied by context. I only care that it's a subset.

Comment: This is called a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

Comment: I've seen $f:X \rightharpoonup Y$ (with "half" of the arrow tip) used for partial functions. It seems to me like a reasonable notation.

Answer (score 1):

These are called [partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function). Wikipedia suggests the notation f : X ↛ Y or f: X ⇸ Y.  I don't know how standard this notation is, so it would be best to explicitly define what you mean.

Yes, I have usually seen $\hookrightarrow$ reserved for injective functions.

Answer (score 1):

In algebraic geometry circles a dotted arrow is common notation for partially defined functions, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38670/65997.

I tend to use $X\rightsquigarrow Y$ because I find it easy to miss the dots etc.. Also the other arrows mentioned above tend to have different meanings in analysis, so they end up confusing the writer/reader. $X\nrightarrow Y$ and the like seems to me to signify "not an arrow" or else they are very close to $\mapsto$, which I tend to reserve for the pointwise map.

Probably macroing $X\xrightarrow{\tiny\mbox{ loc.}} Y$ or $X\xrightarrow{\tiny\mbox{ partial}} Y$ would prove more effient for more writers/readers.

Alternatively one could make the categorical switch of considering $X\to Y$ to signify a partial function. I guess in your context this won't do because it matters to distinguish the local and the global.