# The Pearson correlation coefficient ρ(x, y) of two random variables x and y with var(x) = var(y)

Tags: correlation

Can you help with this problem please?
[image: how to solve this problem with var(x)=var(y)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear regression obtains$$0=\operatorname{cov}\left(Y-a^\ast X,\,X\right)=\operatorname{cov}\left(Y,\,X\right)-a^\ast\operatorname{Var}X,$$so in the equal-variance case$$\rho=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,\,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}X\operatorname{Var}Y}}=a^\ast.$$

Comment: thank you! I know the part of  correlation coefficient.  But I'm confused why from min linear regression you could get cov(Y-a*X,X)=0

Comment: @Thomas For that I recommend you learn how least-squares regression works, preferably from sources that make the geometric interpretation explicit. The key insight is that $Y=a^\ast X+\eta$ with $\eta$ a noise variable "orthogonal" to $X$, in a vector space of random variables for which covariance is an inner product. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071367/whats-so-special-about-standard-deviation/3071375#3071375) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393395/covariance-intuition/3393470#3393470).

Comment: very good explanation. thank you! I have just watched a video to know more about its geometric explanation.

Comment: @Thomas Which video? Maybe I should watch it (although I probably already have, if it's a 3blue1brown video).

Comment: Sorry it's a video in bilibili. not an English video. If you want the video, i can send you the link haha.

Answer (score 0):

Please show some effort. Here some hints:

- Start from the linear regression framework and rewrite, using the linearity of expectation $E[(X-aY-b)^2]$  as a polynomial in $a,b$ ;
- Find the extrema of the polynomial using $\partial_a=0$ and $\partial_b=0$. This is a linear system that can be solved ;
- Compare explicitely the expression you obtain with the Pearson correlation coefficient ;