# What does the "standard" in "standard deviation" mean?

Tags: statistics, terminology, standard-deviation

I know what the standard deviation is. However, I can't make sense of its name. What does the word "standard" refer to?

- Is it a synonym for mean, so that the "standard deviation" is the "deviation from the mean value"?
- Is it a methodology, so that the "standard deviation" is the "standard way of determining the deviation" from the mean?

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#History) that the term *standard deviation* was coined by Karl Pearson in 1894. As far as I could see, his cited article [Contributions to the Mathematical Theory of Evolution](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsta.1894.0003) does indeed introduce the term, but doesn't comment on the chosen name.

Comment: I believe the term derives from the notion that, given a normal distribution, we can speak in terms of "standard units".  That is, $n\sigma$ has a meaning independent of the parameters of the specific distribution.

Comment: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175436/why-is-it-called-the-standard-deviation/175812) is a relevant discussion.

Comment: I'd always thought of standard in this context as meaning like "typical" or "commonplace". Every point in a sample deviates from the mean by a certain amount, and this particular amount of deviation is typical.

Comment: The mean deviations always evaluate to $0.$ We get rid of this by first squaring. This gives a *standard* deviation.

Comment: This might be a good question for the [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Terms of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/s.html) pages mention Pearson's *Contributions* (1894), but also say that "standard deviation" was used by Pearson in a lecture in 1893. Highlighted from *Contributions* is the footnote (pg 80): "I had always found it more convenient to work with the standard-deviation than with the probable error or the modulus, in terms of which the error-function is usually tabulated." This suggests that Pearson used "standard" as something of an honorific, to set the calculation above competing notions.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [the discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175436/why-is-it-called-the-standard-deviation/175812) @lulu linked to, Karl Pearson coined the term without explaining the choice. But whether or not he wanted to call it the standard deviation for the reason your second bullet-point guessed, it's certainly earned that motivation. There are [a number of other deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviation_(statistics)) in statistics, but the standard deviation has several advantages:

- It has [a natural interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071367/whats-so-special-about-standard-deviation/3071375) in terms of a quotient space of variables;
- It's easy to calculate for a lot of interesting probability distributions, and well-defined for an even broader range of them ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) alternative requires much more of a distribution to be well-defined);
- It's the square root of the variance, which is already interesting because it's the second cumulant, and nicely expressed in terms of various generating functions in statistics;
- Central limit theorems, including the classical one, motivate an interest in Gaussian distributions, which are characterized by their mean and variance as parameters of a linear transformation reducing them to the standard Gaussian distribution;
- The variance's generalization to multivariate statistics is easily studied with linear algebra;
- If each observation in a dataset has Gaussian noise of the same variance, maximum likelihood estimation is equivalent to OLS, again easily studied with linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $pr[ \mu - \sigma \le x \le \mu + \sigma] = .68$,  $pr[ \mu - 2\sigma \le x \le \mu + 2\sigma] = .95$, and $pr[ \mu - 3\sigma \le x \le \mu + 3\sigma] = .99$. So it provides a useful rule of thumb for thinking about how likely a realization of $x$ is to be within 1, 2, or 3 standard deviations of its mean in terms of $\sigma$. As .05 and .01 are common levels for tests, this is helpful for back-of-the-envelope calculations about confidence intervals.