# Mathematical Proof of the Classical Assumptions.

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

I am studying in class regression analysis and we just went through the classical assumptions. I was wondering, is there a mathematical way to prove that $V(Y_i)=σ^2$ and  $Cov(Y_i,Y_j)=0$? Since they are assumptions, maybe there is no way to prove them. However, if a way of proving it existed I would appreciate it very much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We just assume the $Y_i$ are homoscedastic and uncorrelated. If you look at certain random variables [as elements of a vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071367/whats-so-special-about-standard-deviation/3071375), this is (to within a factor $\propto\sigma^2$ dependent on our definition of the inner product) an orthonormality assumption.

Comment: What are you asking? There is no 'proof', but maybe some reason behind making these assumptions.