# corr(x,y) = a, corr(y,z) = b, corr(x,z) = ? from $cos(\alpha+\beta)$ why it is a range.

Tags: correlation

Question:
$$corr(x,y) = a, corr(y,z) = b, corr(x,z) = ?$$
Here $corr$ is the correlation.

I know the answer

$$cos(\alpha + \beta) \leq corr(x,z) \leq cos(\alpha - \beta), \textrm{where } cos(\alpha) = a, cos(\beta) = b.$$

And the idea is making the correlation matrix positive semi-definite:
$$
\left|\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & a & x \\
  a & 1& b \\
  x & b& 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\right|
\geq 0$$
But from the point view of sample vectors $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}, \textbf{z},$ without loss of generality , we assume they are all mean 0. Then the correlation is the $cos$ angle of two vectors. Thus
$$corr(x,z)  = cos(\alpha - \beta)\textrm{ or } cos(\alpha + \beta).$$

Why will it be a range? Can anyone point my mistake?

Comment: Seems you use corr(x,y)=a and b at same time. Intentionally?

Comment: @coffeemath sorry, it's a typo, have corrected it, I don't understand from the point view of geometry, how can it be a range but not two numbers.

Comment: @user6703592, Do you have a proof why this is the case. I don't understand why it is cosine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While random variables comprise a vector space (I've discussed this perspective [in detail](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3071375) before), it's not $2$-dimensional, so the third angle needn't be $\alpha\pm\beta$. If you want to visualize this, it's best to consider the in-face angles meeting at the apex of a tetrahedron, whose other vertices' positions relative to that apex are the three vectors $x,\,y,\,z$.

Comment: exactly! I am restricted within the 2-dim space. Thanks.